# NoMethodError running cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara, nomethoderror

I'm getting a fail whenever I try to run this cucumber test on a rails app-
The 'And I click' step definition is working elsewhere, it fails every time here though!
And I can't find anywhere I've used the method `start_with?'

Here's the error output:

```
    And I click "Add a Line Item"                            # features/step_definitions/first_test_steps.rb:17
  undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  ./features/step_definitions/first_test_steps.rb:18:in `/^I click "(.*?)"$/'
  features/create_quote.feature:19:in `And I click "Add a Line Item"'
```

And here's the code for my step definition:

```
When /^I click "(.*?)"$/ do |this|
 click_on(this)
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If "Add a Line Item" is link then use

```
first(:link, "Add a Line Item")
```

and if "Add a Line Item"  is button then use

```
first(:button, "Add a Line Item")
```

Comment: It's a button - where should I be using this code? Can you tell me why it's failing currently?

Comment: replace click_on(this) with page.first(:link, "Add a Line Item").click

Comment: Capybara version 2 is now upgraded with some changes so it is failing. you should use:-> first(:button, "#{this}") inside the when step definition